# Collinearity problem (Newton-Gauss line)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

I had some troubles with this problem :

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral. $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of
>   the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. The sides $AB$ and $CD$ are extended
>   until they intersect. The intersection point is $E$. The sides $AD$
>   and $BC$ are extended until they intersect. The intersection point is
>   $F$. Let $P$ be the midpoint of the segment $[EF]$. Prove that $M$, $N$, $P$ are 
>   collinear.

[image]

First, I found that a quadrilateral in which the opposite sides interesect is also known as a *complete quadrilateral*.
Then, the line $M-N-P$ is known as *Newton-Gauss line* and the problem above as *Newton's Problem*.

I've taught about solving it using areas. I've used the property that *median divides the triangle in two echivalent triangles (with the same area)*. Many properties can be derived from it.

I haven't figure out, but I'm interested in a proof using areas. I would appreciate some suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I remember this is a IMO shortlist problem .. I am forgetting the year.

Comment: @Sawarnik Probably before 2000.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ denote the area of $ABCD$.

**Lemma 1:** The locus of points $X$ in the interior of $ABCD$ such that $|XAB|+|XCD|=\frac{S}{2}$ is a line segment.

In triangle $ADE$, consider a translation of $AB$ to $ES$ and $CD$ to $ET$. Thus, $|XES|=|XAB|$ and $|XET|=|XCD|$. Thus, $|XAB|+|XCD|=|XES|+|XET|=|XSET|=|EST|+|XST|$. Since $S$ and $T$ are fixed points, it follows that $|XST|$ is constant, so the locus of $X$ is the segment made by the intersection of the line parallel to $ST$ with $ABCD$. Further note that if $X$ is outside $ABCD$, then we have $|XAB|-|XCD|=\frac{S}{2}$ or $|XCD|-|XAB|=\frac{S}{2}$.$_\square$

Note that since $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$, $|AMB|=|BMC|$ and $|AMD|=|CMD|$, so $|AMB|+|CMD|=\frac{S}{2}$, so $M$ lies on the locus of $X$. Similarly, $N$ lies on the locus of $X$.

Now note that since $EP=PF$, $|PAB|=\frac{1}{2}|FAB|$ since the distance between $P$ and $AB$ is half of the distance between $F$ and $AB$. Similarly, $|PCD|=\frac{1}{2}|FCD|$. Thus, we have $|PAB|-|PCD|=\frac{1}{2} (|FAB|-|FCD|) = \frac{S}{2}$, so $P$ also lies on this line.

Therefore, $M$, $N$, $P$ are collinear.

Comment: What are S and T point mentioned?

Comment: @rne They are mentioned as part of the construction: translate $AB$ so $A$ maps to $E$, and define the corresponding translated point $B$ maps to as $S$. The definition of $T$ is similar.

Answer (score 3):

In fact there is an alternate, nice, proof using areas that I got, using a link found in the Wikipedia article, in the book by Johnson,  "Modern geometry; An Elementary Treatise on the Geometry of the Triangle and the Circle, Houghton Mifflin Ed., 1929" [available online](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=wu.89043163211&view=1up&seq=79&q1=91) (public domain), page 61-62.
I reproduce here the two pages.

[image]

[image]

Nice, isn't it ?

Comment: The reason behind concluding that the midpoints of $AA'$,$AN$ and $AS$ are collinear is : In $\triangle ABC$ , the midpoints of $AB$, $AC$ and cevian $AD$ are collinear. The proof comes from *Mid-point theorem*.